# How to implement Menu bar inside QGraphicsView?

Tags: qt, qt4, qgraphicsview, qmenubar

I have a QGraphicsView which shows images dynamically. I also used fitInView feature to resize the window. Now I need to add the menu bar at the top of the QGraphicsView. How to implement this? Please help. I am new in Qt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As beginner it is probably easiest to place your **QGraphicsView** into a **QVBoxLayout** and create a **QMenuBar** and insert it above your graphics view.

```
QMenuBar *bar = new QMenuBar();
ui->yourVerticalLayout->insertWidget( 0, bar );

QMenu* yourMenu = bar->addMenu("Your Menu title");
QAction* yourFirstAction = yourMenu->addAction("Your First Action");
```